# Is ubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic same as ubuntu 13

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, server

I'm new to the Linux environment and 
I'm using a server it has as a kernel `Linux Ubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic`.

I want to install same operating system in my desktop so please suggest me which version of the Ubuntu operating system i should use.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Ubuntu 14.04. It [currently uses](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-generic) the 3.13 kernel series.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your desktop version may not be the same if your desktop is a 32-bit machine and the server is a 64-bit machine (or vice versa).   Also, kernel versions are updated as part of the Ubuntu software maintenance process - You might install a certain kernel version and this can be upgraded as part of the maintenance process.